# How can i add dropdowns based on number present in the database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, dropdown

For an example 
In my database i have a column name **floor** and the value i have inserted is **4** 
i want to show in a form like if the value of the floor is 4, i want to show drop downs based on the value present in the database here it is **4**

```
<select name="floor">
<option value=0>Floor</option>
<option value=1>First Floor</option>
<option value=2>Second Floor</option>
<option value=3>Third Floor</option>
<option value=4>Fourth Floor</option>
</select>
```

How can i achieve this one, is it possible..?  please suggest edit if question not reach the standards.

Comment: @S.I. Can you give an example or anycode..?

Comment: Do you have database connection? Any php code?

Comment: Just a simple query `SELECT * FROM floor WHERE floor_id = 1` this will select floor 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly here is one very simple example since I don't know anything about DB and your other source:

```
// Connection data (server_address, database, name, password)
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'yourdbname';
$userdb = 'yourdbuser';
$passdb = 'yourdbpass';

try {
    // Connect and create the PDO object
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

    // Selects the rows in which "floor_id" is 2
    $sql = "SELECT *  FROM floor WHERE floor_id = 2";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // Parse the result set
    echo '<select name="floor">';

    while($row = $result->fetch()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['floor_value'].'">'.$row['floor_name'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
    $conn = null;        // Disconnect
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This snippet will show on the page select dropdown which are with value 2.
More information about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Few examples for [`MySQLi_*` and `PDO`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do like this

```
while($row=$handler->fetch_assoc()){
  echo '<option value="'.$row['fieldid'].'">'.$row['fieldname'].'</option>';
}
```

handler would be your own variable

Comment: Do i need to store the fieldname and id in a seperate table for fetching..?